# How to display images from database in ReactJS?

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I've started working with React recently.

I have project with ReactJS front-end and ASP.NET back-end.

I keep path to images in my database. And in React script I want to get them.

My app starts from "Index.html". My photos located in "PizzaPhotos" folder.

Here is my project tree:

[image]

Here is my fetch to get info(includes images):
[image]

If I use just "img src="" it works correctly:

[image]

Path to photos which I use is: "../src/PizzaPhotos/image.jpg"

And it doesn't work, all what I get is: `[x]` in browser.

Maybe solution is very simple, but at this moment I can't do it myself.

Answer (score 0):

They should be paths to your `public` folder where you should have the images stored. The public folder, depending your configuration, is what is served to the browser.

Comment: i used what u've say and now it's just don't display anything.
It's seems like react blocked image to display.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, you should put the images in your `/public` folder and then reference the folder using the `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` variable. React does not recommend this approach (compared to using import statements) but notes that there are legitimate use cases. More here: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder